# What is the name of that theorem?

Tags: fourier-analysis, fourier-series, fourier-transform

Here is the statement :

> Let $f:\mathbb{R}\to \mathbb{C}$ a continuous map which is $\mathcal{C}^1$ by pieces and such that $f\in \mathcal{L}^1(\mathbb{R})$. Moreover, $\hat f  \equiv 0$ in $\mathbb{R}-[-1/2,1/2]$. Then for all $x\in\mathbb{R}-\mathbb{Z}$, $$f(x)=\frac{1}{\pi}\sum \limits_{n=-\infty}^{+\infty}\frac{\sin(\pi(x-n))}{x-n}f(n).$$

Thanks in advance !

Comment: Isn't this saying that the function is entirely determined by its values at integers? How can it be true?

Comment: I believe it's called the "$0=1$ Theorem", named after one of its most important corollaries.

Comment: @DavidC.Ullrich Apparently Shannon worked on it

Comment: @Maman No, Shannon worked on a theorem that you're confusing with what you said. If you assume that the support of the Fourier transform of $f$ is contained in $[-1,1]$ or $[-\pi,\pi]$ or something then what you said becomes true - what you said is _obviously_ false, for reasons that have been pointed out. The thing Shannon did is called something with the word "sampling" in the name, I believe, if you want to try to find it.

Comment: @DavidC.Ullrich I added an important hypothesis...

Comment: This reminds me of the Sampling Theorem in some sense.

Comment: It might be helpful to note that $(-1)^n\sin(\pi\,x)=\sin(\pi(x-n))$.

Comment: @JuliánAguirre Indeed, so is it the Shannon's sampling theorem ?

Comment: I am no expert, but it certainly looks like iit.

Comment: @Maman, for more detail, see [Chapter 3 here](http://www.cmap.polytechnique.fr/~mallat/papiers/WaveletTourChap1-2-3.pdf).

Comment: @Chester nice references. So it is Shannon Whittaker sampling thorem !